# How to set default picture

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating little system with uploading data into mysql with picture. I want to have a default picture for data if the picture was not uploaded with data.

I do not know how to do it. I think it must be done with file_exist().

But i do not know how.

Here is my code for displaying image to data:

```
<td><img src="../otk/pc/uploads/<?php echo $row['obrazok'];?>" height="100" width="100"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. This is old i solved this few weeks ago so okay.